# Trying to make sliding puzzel game in unity. But the puzzel piece don't move

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make simple sliding puzzel game in unity. I used https://youtu.be/rJFprTG3wE0 this video as tutorial. In the video block move if clicked but mine doesn't.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

public class gamebasic : MonoBehaviour
{

```
[SerializeField] public Transform empty =null;
private Camera _camera;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    _camera = Camera.main;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = _camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction);
        if (hit)
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(a: empty.position, b:  hit.transform.position) < 1)
            {
                Vector2 lastemptyposition = empty.position;
                empty.position = hit.transform.position;
                hit.transform.position = lastemptyposition;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my code and I am using visual studio 2017 version 15.9.39 and unity 2020.3.11f1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the video he makes a comment about changing the value of the distance, if your reference to the empty transform is correct that might be the reason.

You can make this a public variable and test different values, like this:

```
[SerializeField] private float maxDistanceToEmpty = 2f;
```

and then you change that line to

```
if (Vector2.Distance(a: empty.position, b:  hit.transform.position) < maxDistanceToEmpty )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I changed number to 4 and it fixed my prolem